# Notation for a fraction of $n!$

Tags: notation, factorial, article-writing

Suppose I want to write $n!/2$, can I just write $\tfrac{1}{2}n!$ or is that easily confused with $(\tfrac{1}{2}n)!$ and I have to write $\tfrac{1}{2}(n!)$?

Are there precedence rules for these situations (like we have in Computer Programming languages C/C++/Python ...)?

Comment: $\frac{1}{2} n!$ means $\frac{1}{2}(n!)$. In general, the $n!$ notation has a higher precedence that arithmetic operations.

Comment: There are similar questions for $1/2n!$ as to whether it is $\dfrac1{2(n!)}$ or $\dfrac1{(2n)!}$ or $\dfrac{n!}2$.  Ambiguity is a risk without brackets even  with conventions and it is for writers  to consider how much risk they are willing to take.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Precedence.html

Comment: @SohamSaha, why didn't I find that myself. Tunnel vision...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a **Common Convention** that $n!$ is always taken together.

Compare $\sum n!$ , it is $\sum (n!)$ , not $(\sum n)!$

Compare $\log n!$ , it is $\log (n!)$ , not $(\log n)!$

Likewise $mn!$ is $m(n!)$ , not $(mn)!$

Thus $\frac12n!$ is $\frac12(n!)$ , not $(\frac12n)!$

When we want the other way , we have to use the Brackets.
When Context is weird , always use Brackets to aid the readers.

### ADDENDUM :

Checked with Wolfram , which agrees with this **Convention** :

[image: factorial]

We can see that Wolfram is not taking $3n!$ to mean $(3n)!$ , where $n=2$ will not work.
Wolfram took $3n!$ to mean $3(n!)$ , where $n=2$ will work.

Answer (score 3):

We have precedences rules stating that e.g. multiplication must be evaluated before addition, so $1+2*3$ has a unique meaning. Commonly $!$ is assigned a precedence like all other unary operators, i.e. $\frac12n!$ means $\frac12(n!)$.

Comment: Not exactly. It has **higher** precedence that the unitary $-$. The expression $-n!$ means $-(n!)$. If $-$ and $!$ were assigned the same precedence $-n!$ would be ambiguous.

Comment: That's correct, but in general unary operators are so specialised that I thought it would be better to leave their relative precedence out (I'm not sure there are common rules for the relationship between operators that are only used in different branches of maths). I guess unary $-$ and $!$ are common enough that it should have been mentioned. (I even started wondering if I knew what $(-\frac12)!$ is).

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity [Perhaps](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28-1%2F2%29%21) $(-\frac12)!=\Gamma(-\frac12+1)=\sqrt{\pi}$